# unity3d prefab cube problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, mesh

Unity generates prefab made from a cube in Blender. I am using the fbx-format.

Generates x++ and z++;

The problem I have is the white stripe between generated cubes. Is there way to remove it?

[image: Result]

Comment: Try changing the Green Texture Map. I used to have the same problem on my skyboxes. Select the texture in UnityEditor and change TextureWrapMode to clamp!

Comment: code doesn't matter, because this stripe appears even if i place blocks side by side manually. Changing TextureWrapMode to clamp doesn't helps too. I think i do something wrong with texture or material.

Comment: does your texture have a margin outside the UV islands? it could be a problem with mips. try to "bleed" the color outside the uv layout (i dunno how thats called professionally sry)